# Split set in java

Tags: java, set

I am trying to find the best way to retain the first half of a set in java.
My Set (java.util.Set) contains 60000 elements and I need to retain only 30000 of it.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: `set.stream().limit(30000).collect(toSet())`

Comment: What do you mean by "first 30000"? Sets are, in general, unordered. Do you just want to retain "any" 30k elements?

Comment: correct, I meant any 30k elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Guava library, we can use Lists.partition() method that splits the list into consecutive sublists, every list specified size

Java Doc:

https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-

You can also use

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#subList-int-int-

For set specifically

```
Set<Integer> subset = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterables.limit(set, 30000));
```

Guava Doc :

https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit-java.lang.Iterable-int-

User streams:

```
yourSet.stream().limit(30000).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I am particularly looking for Set, which does not have partition method

Comment: Iterables.limit is what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @user4202236 see latest edit

Answer (score 1):

There are no direct methods in Java's Set interface for slicing or keeping a particular section of the components. You can convert a set into a list, do the needed operation on the retained members, and then build a new set from the retained elements if you want to keep the first 30,000 elements from the set.

```
// Your original set with 60,000 elements
Set<YourElementType> originalSet = new HashSet<>();

// Convert the Set to a List
List<YourElementType> originalList = new ArrayList<>(originalSet);

// Retain the first 30,000 elements
List<YourElementType> retainedList = originalList.subList(0, 30000);

// Create a new Set from the retained elements
Set<YourElementType> retainedSet = new HashSet<>(retainedList);
```